# How to grant the delete privilege for any table in a schema?

Tags: oracle, database-design, sqlplus, sql-delete, delete-row

I want to give my Oracle user privileges to **delete** rows from *any* table within a schema.

What is the syntax for this?

Comment: I'm *almost* sure that there's official Oracle **documentation** for this somewhere.......

Comment: [Oracle 9i Managing User Privileges and Roles](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm).  Since you didn't say which Oracle database you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do that. Oracle does not have support to this. Theoretically you could use [CRATE SCHEMA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6014.htm) statement, but even this does not exactly what you expect. You really have to grant tables one by one.

On the other hand when using PL/SQL and execute immediate it is just 5 lines of code.

Comment: Can I use grant all priveleges instead to grant delete on all the tables in a schema?

Comment: @java123999 - you can only grant (much) more powerful privileges than you need, which is bad practice (see 'principle of least privilege'). Granting specific privileges to only the objects that are required is the way to go; it's very slightly more work to do that but the advantages far outweigh that.